# Why is eating not included in Karmendriyas?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta

> Karmendriyas literally means ‘organs of action’.
>
> Every human being is endowed with eleven indriyas or sense-organs.
> These organs are five jñānendriyas, five karmendriyas and a mind.
>
> The five karmendriyas or organs of action are:
>
> Vāk - speech
> Pāṇi - hands
> Pāda - feet
> Pāyu - excretory organ
> Upastha -
> organ of reproduction
>
> These have been called ‘karmendriyas’ because they are the indriyas or
> sense organs responsible for karma or action.

[Source](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Karmendriyas)

These same Karmendriyas are found everywhere and there seems to be no disagreement in the list.

---

**But, Why is organ of eating and action of eating not included in Karmendriyas?**

---

The immediate response is to pair it up with Vak or organ of speech and say they both are same. This is not satisfactory as speech is made by vocal cords and food is assimilated by stomach and intestines.  Both use common opening of mouth, but food goes in and speech goes out. You can see this with reproductory organ and excretory organ, both uses the same outlet, but are categorized differently.

Another possible objection is that eating is not a karma. But this is not so convincing as excretion is categorized as karma.

So, Why is organ of eating and action of eating not included in Karmendriyas?

Comment: Maybe the soul does not directly control the mouth and has to tell the brain to do it instead. Thus, it is an extension of Vāk. Makes sense as you don't voluntarily control a lot of your eating process.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa how is process of excretion voluntary then? It is very similar amd innvolves the same organs.

Comment: Excretion probably includes chemical creation (they are excreted) which is needed for life. In fact, it is probably the most important thing the soul does, as it is necessary for all living things to live. Eating is much simpler and less involved and can be outsourced to the brain.